# How do LGBTQ+ people, who don't want to out themselves on their primary account, provide feedback since you need 50 rep to post on meta?

Tags: discussion, meta

### Original question:

There's some of fairly offensive stuff being left up and it seems that the staff believe it's harmless when it's not. I can't even speak up without outing myself to the greater world, though.

### Further comments:

Technically I guess it's 5 rep, but given that most discussion happens in comments it's really 50.

These rep requirements are, of course, there for a reason, but the effect is still the silencing of inclusion in the discussion of people impacted by the discussion.

A moderator manually gave me the meta permission, but it doesn't seem to have worked.

How can we make sure people like me can be included, without being forced to post semi-inflammatory fake-questions on the main site?

Comment: One way, albeit time consuming, is to submit 25 accepted suggested edits. Each one rewards 2 reputation

Comment: If you see offensive content in any form you should be able to flag it even at 1 reputation.

Comment: @TylerH Flagging has a reputation requirement of 15.

Comment: @TylerH The staff has already declared the content as non-offensive, and yet I am offended by it. The next step is supposed to be a discussion on meta, right?

Comment: @FrightenedTransGirl link?

Comment: @gnat as mentioned by OP they want to comment, which is 50.

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl I don't want to make this question about that one, so I won't be posting a link here. If I have energy later I will ask about it, but just this is too draining right now.

Comment: Almost all of the discussion about this is happening on the main meta though.

Comment: @Magisch Technically, a valid answer is to participate in the site to earn rep. That's a fairly large hurdle for someone who is currently angry and would like to make themselves heard, though.

Comment: @FrightenedTransGirl Thats correct, thats why I qualified it with "albeit time consuming". I'm not aware of another / easier way to achieve what you're asking for, however. a mod can not grant a permission to comment, so it may be the only avenue available right now.

Comment: It seems that mods (or maybe staff?) do actually have a "give permission" button as I got a notification that I was granted the meta permission after asking the original question. It didn't actually work though, so I had to use the "ask about own question via link" option to create this. That being said, if this was the route mods would require proof, and needing to out yourself to mods in order to post is... also not really great.

Comment: @FrightenedTransGirl The ask about your own meta post route bypasses rep requirements, but mods can't actually grant meta permission either. What likely happened is that you recieved one upvote on your question, which puts your reputation at 6, which grants the "participate on meta" privilege. Then, when you self-deleted your question, that reputation was undone as well. There is no way for mods to grant you permission to comment anywhere without you having 50 reputation, it is a floating privilege that can be gained and lost based on current rep, and is checked every time before you comment.

Comment: @FrightenedTransGirl You can contact staff directly without any reputation requirements at this form, however: https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact

Comment: @Magisch Oh, really, it has been so long I must have forgotten that. Seems silly though to restrict that, at least for things like rude/abusive or spam.

Comment: This is a bit tricky - if you're not comfortable posting it here, and don't have enough rep to comment on your sock account, there's not many options left. There's the contact form, and alternatively mod flags (although you'd risk outing yourself to mods if you don't get the 15 rep required to flag on this account. It's not too bad though, it's 7 suggested edits if you don't post). That assumes it's here on meta.SO though - if it's on meta.SE, you can comment at 5 (but still can't flag 'til 15), so it's slightly less complicated there

Comment: It's not that I'm not comfortable posting it here, it's that this post right here has consumed the energy I was going to dedicate to that one. There are some answers here that should be answers though, such as the staff contact form, and the fact that meta.SE has different requirements. The real answer is indeed "this is tricky" -- if I try to say anything further I'm going to start saying inflammatory things again so I'm just going to go away now. Please post these answers as answers so this isn't just a huge comment chain.

Comment: Like everybody else I guess. I'm not being rude but if the special treatment door is opened once, everyone will want it opened for them too.

Comment: What would being LGBTQ+ on Stack Overflow have to do with providing feedback about questions or answers on Stack Overflow?  Help me to understand this; we've gone through a bit of an upheaval in the last 24 hours and I'm still not putting two and two together on this one.  For context:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334909/175248

Comment: I have plenty rep.  Please link the offensive stuff and I'll flag it.

Comment: Note that I find this request for special privileges for some demographics to be offensive in itself.  Also, I'm not all that impressed by the deliberate posting of grossly off-topic questions on the main site in order to gain privilege:(

Answer (score 55):

You do not need to "out" yourself to have an opinion on an issue. You don't need to state your identity at all (and generally shouldn't, unless it's really relevant, like if you're the maintainer of an open-source library answering a question about how a bug was resolved).

**This ability to remain relatively anonymous has been a key feature of the Stack Exchange network since its very inception.** It's *awesome*: it's a killer feature of this site. **It creates *true* inclusivity, because it allows *everyone* to participate, regardless of their identity.** Whether it's gender identity that you don't want to reveal, or maybe you're on the autism spectrum, or maybe you're just a privacy fanatic. Doesn't matter. You don't even have to tell us why you're choosing to keep private things private.

The little user card at the bottom of a post is only there to provide *attribution* of your answer; it is otherwise not relevant who was the originator of the content. Another way of putting this is, we encourage everyone to evaluate content on its own merits, not based on who wrote it.

I hope this won't be taken as offensive, because I certainly don't mean it that way, but your views on the issue should *not* carry greater weight because of your identity. It doesn't matter whether you're *cis*-gender or *trans*-gender. You're still a person, and more importantly, you're a user of the Stack Exchange network, so your well-reasoned opinion on how the Stack Exchange network does and should operate is intrinsically valuable.

Just post your views under your normal user account, with all of its associated privileges.

If you aren't comfortable revealing your identity on the Internet at all, well, then that's perfectly fine, too. We don't require that users use their "real names" or disclose *any* aspects of their identities in order to create an account.

The worst thing that can possibly happen is that your Stack Overflow account is associated with an entity who has a particular opinion about an issue. Which...seems fair, since that is actually your opinion. What we're trying to prevent here is pre-judging people for who they *are*. It needs to still be okay to judge people's ideas, as long as it is done respectfully.

Comment: If only SO staff would understand this...!

Comment: I like this answer very much, but I also think it slightly overestimates the judging by merit of content only. Inevitably humans do take the identity of a poster into account at least partly and the identity is partly revealed when posting opinions about more political than technical matters. A truly anonymous way of contributing might be something desirable. Something like: don't display my name below this content and in the post history and don't link to my profile.

Comment: "unless it's really relevant" That's the point. It *does* matter if an opinion on LGBTQ+ issues is coming from a queer person as opposed to someone who is not, because queer people *are queer* and can provide a firsthand perspective in much the same way as your maintainer example. The fact that there is a user card at all - that the poster *is attributed* at all - means that posts are never truly anonymous, especially if their main account, especially if it's well-established on this site, uses a common persona they use elsewhere.

Comment: I'm going to follow up with what about those of us who have already identified ourselves on our account?

Comment: @randomusername do you mean people whose names are known or visible (as mine is) and who might not want to flag creepy or insulting stuff because flagging would make others think that they are LBblah? Or do you have some other scenadio in mind?

Answer (score 18):

The minimum reputation needed for participation here is 5: if you can earn 5 points on SO (one question or answer upvote or one accepted answer or two approved edits) then you can post a question or answer here.

Answering is by far the preferred way of contributing to these discussions. Comments may be deleted at any time; just because a comment appears to have been overlooked doesn't mean it will be left around indefinitely: it's entirely possible that the entire thread will be wiped out when moderators are able to get to it. Answers will remain accessible to their authors even if deleted; a deleted comment is effectively gone for everyone.

Also: you can always flag comments on your *own* answers, but won't be able to flag comments on other people's posts without earning at least 15 reputation first. So there again, answering (or asking) works in your favor by allowing you to participate in moderating the conversation.

If all else fails, you can participate (ask/answer) over on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com) without any reputation.

Comment: Eh, I'd recommend against posting on M.SE right now; there won't be a positive reception, and it's just going to be an incredibly negative experience.

Comment: ...and SO meta is going the same way, it seems:(

Answer (score 4):

I would disagree with your assertion that the discussion happens in the comments. It seems that way if you look at it from the perspective of just a few minutes, but comments are frequently removed, easily buried under other comments, and do not get that many votes.

Long term, answers are far more influential and impactful. Remember, the Stack Exchange network is not a network of forums but rather a democratic question and answer site. The goal is not to convince a couple of people in the comments, but rather the far larger number of lurkers and less vocal participants who use votes as their influence.

An answer with many upvotes is going to have a far greater chance of impact compared to a comment with a proportional number of upvotes.

The best thing for you to do under this format is to use your account to answer this question yourself with what you would want to see done.

Answer (score 4):

There isn’t anything saying that you need to out yourself.

If you feel you need to, say that you’re an ally instead, or even just say that it’s your opinion, and skate around the question.

I’d say that the most important thing is that the LGBTQ+ community voices their individual opinions on the matter, and answers to the CoC updates are what will drive the conversation.

Once you have a few upvotes on that answer, you’ll be able to comment

It’s heated over there, mainly due to how the changes have been presented, and the fact that tensions have been building due to [moderator firings and resignations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper) (that are a result of questioning the changes to the CoC), [an extremely badly received statement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334248/382667) and [an apology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps) which seems to have had more downvotes since the CoC released.

## TL;DR

The community is talking, and your voice will be heard better in an answer now, than it will be if you wait for more answers to appear. If you don’t want to out yourself, play the role of ally if you need to. What’s important is that your opinions are shared